# Distribucion de Boltzman (listas)

Tags: python

mas que un error es una falta de ideas. Necesito que el programa me genere 50 veces una lista random de 10 numeros del 1 al 10 y que cada vez que la suma de sus partes sea igual a 50 lo ingrese a otra lista para al final mostrar un histograma de lo hallado

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
suma=0 
final=[]
cont=0
cont1=0

while cont==50:
    lista=random.sample(range(1,10),10)
    for i in lista:
        suma=suma+i
        if suma == 50:
           cont1+=1
           final.append(cont)
cont+=1
```

Llevo esto, importe la libreria pandas y matplotlib para el histograma pero la verdad no tengo muy buen manejo de estas.

Comment: Vas a hacer el histograma en base a....??? Las listas que suman más de 50? las que suman menos de 50? O ambas??

Comment: la verdad yo tampoco entiendo muy bien, en el ejercicio que pone el profesor solo lo pone de esa forma y pues la verdad no supe que hacer, yo diria que seria tipo, y = los intentos x=las veces que se cumple el proposito